# Firebase search feature

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code

```
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    //Add the data first
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    mDataabseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserData");


    mSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String mSearchText = mEditText.getText().toString();

            mSearch(mSearchText);
        }
    });
    return rootview;
}

private void mSearch(final String mSearchText) {
    Query searchQuery = mDataabseReference;

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SearchHelper> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<SearchHelper>()
                    .setQuery(searchQuery, SearchHelper.class)
                    .build();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SearchHelper, Search.SearchViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Search.SearchViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final SearchHelper model) {


            String uid = getRef(position).getKey();
          mDataabseReference.child(uid).startAt(mSearchText).endAt(mSearchText + "\uf8ff").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
              @Override
             public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                 for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                      SearchHelper search = dataSnapshot.getValue(SearchHelper.class);
                      mSearchList.add(search);

                  }
              }

              @Override
              public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

              }
              @Override
              public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  SearchHelper search = dataSnapshot.getValue(SearchHelper.class);
                  mSearchList.add(search);
              }

              @Override
              public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

              }
          });
        }
        @Override
        public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }


    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

}

public static class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;

        public SearchViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setName(String title) {
            TextView nameText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            nameText.setText(title);
        }
        public void setUserName(String title) {
            TextView nameText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            nameText.setText(title);
        }
        public void setImage(String image) {
            CircularImageView mDisplayImage = (CircularImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
            Picasso.get().load(image).into(mDisplayImage);
        }
```

No results are showing...

I have tried Childevent and ValueEvent 
I have tried With for loop and without it

Database

[image: edon't image description here]

I dont know whats wrong and im tired of trying because there is no error also and I have no idea where I'm going wrong. Can someone please help me out by pointing out the error?

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Searching in Firebase is always a two-step approach:

1. Order the data
2. Filter the data based on that ordering

You're missing step 1 in your code: nowhere do you indicate what to order on.

For example, if you're trying to search the user date by name, your query would become:

```
mDataabseReference.child(uid)
                  .orderByChild("Name")
                  .startAt(mSearchText).endAt(mSearchText + "\uf8ff")
                  .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Another mistake is that you're looking over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` in `onChildAdded`. But `onChildAdded` already fires for each individual child node, so the loop is not needed:

```
 public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
     SearchHelper search = dataSnapshot.getValue(SearchHelper.class);
     mSearchList.add(search);
 }
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.mItemViewType' on a null object reference

Comment: That seems unrelated to the mistakes I pointed out in my answer. Note that there is quite a lot going in in the code you shared, with both a FirebaseUI adapter, and your own listener. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to learn how to isolae the problem.

Comment: OK i returned null in oncreateview... my bad but the code stilll doesnt get results... now its just showing recycleritem item saying Name and Username instead of getting its values